# Change BrowserWindow position dynamically in electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating a menu in window.js when we click on it the current browser window position will change. I have my app.js file where I have created my browserWindow and have set x,y . Now how can I change the x,y values of current browserWindow ?

My BrowserWindow in app.js

```
 window = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 265,
      height: screenheight,
      x: screenXPosition,
      y: 0,
      icon: "icon.ico",
      skipTaskbar: true,
      alwaysOnTop: false,
      show: false,
      frame: false,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      transparent: true,
      // resizable: false
    })
```

I have one Window.js file where my menu is .Is it required to pass current window instance to window.js? If yes, how should I pass current browserWindow instance to window.js to app.js? and how can we change the x,y values?
Is it possible ?
my window.js menu

```
//Menu
const menu = new Menu()
// Build menu one item at a time, unlike
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'Settings'

}))
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    type: 'separator'
}))
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'position',
    submenu: [{
            label: 'right',
            role: '25%',
            type: 'checkbox',
            checked: true,
            click: function () {
                console.log('25%');
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'left',
            role: '50%',
            click: function () {
                console.log('50%');
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'separator'
        },
        {
            label: 'center',
            role: '50%',
            click: function () {
                console.log('50%');
            }
        }
    ]
}))
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    menu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow())
}, false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menuItem click there is a argument for the current `browserWindow`.

To set the x and y position you can use `window.setPosition(x, y)`.

So your menuItem code would be something like this:

```
{
    label:   'right',
    role:    '25%',
    type:    'checkbox',
    checked: true,
    click:   function (item, focusedWindow) {
        console.log('25%');
        focusedWindow.setPosition(10, 10);
    }
}
```

[window.setPosition](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetpositionx-y-animate)

[menuItem arguments](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu-item/#new-menuitemoptions)

Comment: What If we want focusedWindow in window.js? i.e. not in the menu but in the main file of window.js

Comment: I have checked with remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow() but didn't work for me It is giving error Uncaught Error: Could not call remote function 'setPosition'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from undefined

Comment: how do you change `minWidth` with `remote`??

Comment: @oldboy I'm sorry, I don't really follow. Could you explain? Or perhaps create a new question?

Comment: nm i figured it out. `setMinimumSize()`